# Передаю JSON из JS в PHP, затем хочу чтобы PHP выслал данные письмом. В чем ошибка?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Здравствуйте, подскажите где ошибка?
JSON строку сформировал и выслал методом POST в файл PHP, но там срока не декодируется и данные не могу вытащить.

Вот так отсылаю JSON

```
   arrs = {
               "zakazNr": zakaz,
               "telPe": telPe,
               "namePe": namePe,
               "emailPe": emailPe,
               "uwagi": messagePe,
               "position": position
           };
var data = 'param='+JSON.stringify(arrs); $.post('http://site.xyz/mail.php?', data);
```

Это мой файл mail.php

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['param'])){ 
$d = $_POST['param'];
$zakaz = json_decode($d);
$telP = $zakaz->telPe;
$emailP = $zakaz->emailPe;
$nameP = $zakaz->namePe;
$zakazNr = $zakaz->zakazNr;
$uwagiP = $uwagi->uwagi;
$zakazPositionName->position[0]->name;
$zakazPositionCena->position[0]->cena;
$zakazPositionKol->position[0]->kol;
$to = 'appetita@me.com, '.$emailP;
$subject = 'Zamowienie Nr: '.$zakazNr.'z strony';
$message = '<html>
     <head>
<title>'.$nameP.' '.$telP.'</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>'.$zakaz.'</h3>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Imię i Nazwisko: </td><td style="color:#009DF6;">'.$nameP.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Telefon: </td><td style="color:#009DF6;">'.$telP.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Email: </td><td style="color:#009DF6;">'.$emailP.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Uwagi: </td><td style="color:#009DF6;">'.$uwagiP.'</td>
  </tr>

<table></br>';

    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$nameP."<".$emailP.">\r\n"; 
    $headers .= '<table  class="table table-shopping">
                <tr>
                  <td>'.$zakazPositionName.'</td>
                  <td class="td-number text-right" style="font-size: 12px;">'.$zakazPositionCena.'</td>
                  <td class="td-number text-right">'.$zakazPositionKol.'</td>
                  <td class="td-number text-right">'.$zakazPositionCena*$zakazPositionKol.'</td>
                </tr>
       </table>             
                </body>
            </html>'; 


    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в php - `<h3>'.$zakaz.'</h3>`. Вероятно вы хотели написать `<h3>'.$zakazNr.'</h3>`. Кроме того, у вас есть строки `$uwagiP = $uwagi->uwagi;
$zakazPositionName->position[0]->name;
$zakazPositionCena->position[0]->cena;
$zakazPositionKol->position[0]->kol;`, что тоже неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код вполне себе работает, проверяйте ошибки, декод работает.

```
<script>
        arrs = {
               "zakazNr": '1',
               "telPe": 222,
               "namePe": 'zzz',
               "emailPe": 'sss',
               "uwagi": 'ddddd',
               "position": '123'
           };
        var data = 'param='+JSON.stringify(arrs); $.post('test.php?', data, function(r){
            console.log(r);
        });
    </script>
```

Php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['param'])){ 
$d = $_POST['param'];
$zakaz = json_decode($d);
print print_r($zakaz, true);
die;
}
```

В консоли имеем

```
stdClass Object
(
    [zakazNr] => 1
    [telPe] => 222
    [namePe] => zzz
    [emailPe] => sss
    [uwagi] => ddddd
    [position] => 123
)
```